# How to get a multi-level Nested JSON property's value via CROSS APPLY?

Tags: sql, json, sql-server, t-sql

We have JSON data in this format:

```
{
    "id": "f53283cc-5af7-4864-a3f6-86f69d81ae93",
    "SectionId": 5493,
    "Fields": [
        {
            "FieldId": 17943,
            "FieldValue": 
                "[
                    {
                        \"Web_Id\":\"1;#99999984_6_11_018111\",
                        \"EDF\":
                            [
                                {
                                    \"key\":\"Orders\",
                                    \"val\":\"1\"
                                }
                            ],
                        \"CCID\":\"1;#AVSPN004987\",
                        \"G\":null
                    }
                ]",
            "FieldName": "<p>Primary_Product</p>17943",
            "VersionID": 2
        }
    ]
}
```

From this data, I can pull values from the Fields property level like the FieldID, FieldValue, FieldName and VersionID using the query below. However, I would like to know if it's possible to pull the WebId or the CCID from the FieldValue element? Currently, I'm doing a SUBSTRING to get the value:

```
SELECT
  AC_ID
  , FieldID
  , CASE
    WHEN FieldName LIKE '%Item_Description%' THEN 'Item Description'
    WHEN FieldName LIKE '%Item_Number%' THEN 'Item Number'
    WHEN FieldName LIKE '%Primary_Product%' THEN 'Primary Product'
    ELSE ''
    END AS Field
  , CASE
    WHEN FieldID <> '17943' THEN FieldValue
    WHEN FieldID = '17943' THEN SUBSTRING(STUFF(FieldValue, 1, 15, ''), 1, CHARINDEX('"', STUFF(FieldValue, 1, 15, '')) - 1)
    ELSE NULL
    END AS FieldValue
  , SUBSTRING(STUFF(FieldValue, 1, 15, ''), 1, CHARINDEX('"', STUFF(FieldValue, 1, 15, '')) - 1)

FROM CTE_BASE
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(CTE_BASE.Fields)
WITH (
  FieldId VARCHAR(10) '$.FieldId'
  , FieldName VARCHAR(MAX) '$.FieldName'
  , FieldValue VARCHAR(MAX) '$.FieldValue'
) AS CDB
```

Comment: Side note: you might want to consider using XQuery parsing on the `FieldName`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that the `$.FieldValue` part of the JSON is a JSON array stored as a string. But I think that one addiitonal `APPLY` operator will return the expected results.

Simplified test data:

```
DECLARE @json nvarchar(max) = N'{
   "id":"f53283cc-5af7-4864-a3f6-86f69d81ae93",
   "SectionId":5493,
   "Fields":[
      {
         "FieldId":17943,
         "FieldValue":"[{\"Web_Id\":\"1;#99999984_6_11_018111\",\"EDF\":[{\"key\":\"Orders\",\"val\":\"1\"}],\"CCID\":\"1;#AVSPN004987\",\"G\":null}]",
         "FieldName":"<p>Primary_Product</p>17943",
         "VersionID":2
      }
   ]
}'
```

Statement:

```
SELECT *
FROM OPENJSON(@json, '$.Fields') WITH (
  FieldId VARCHAR(10) '$.FieldId', 
  FieldName VARCHAR(MAX) '$.FieldName', 
  FieldValue NVARCHAR(MAX) '$.FieldValue'
) j1
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(j1.FieldValue) WITH (
  Web_Id varchar(50) '$.Web_Id',
  CCID varchar(50) '$.CCID'
) j2
```

| FieldId | FieldName | FieldValue | Web_Id | CCID |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 17943 | <p>Primary_Product</p>17943 | [{"Web_Id":"1;#99999984_6_11_018111","EDF":[{"key":"Orders","val":"1"}],"CCID":"1;#AVSPN004987","G":null}] | 1;#99999984_6_11_018111 | 1;#AVSPN004987 |

Note, that if the `$.FieldValue` part of the stored JSON is stored as JSON array, not as a string, you will need the `AS JSON` modifier to get the nested JSON content.

JSON array as text:

```
DECLARE @json1 nvarchar(max) = N'{
   "Fields":[
      {"FieldValue":"[{\"key\":\"value\"}]"}
   ]
}'
SELECT *
FROM OPENJSON(@json1, '$.Fields') WITH (
  FieldValue NVARCHAR(MAX) '$.FieldValue'
) j1
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(j1.FieldValue) WITH (
  [key] varchar(50) '$.key'
) j2
```

JSON array as JSON:

```
DECLARE @json2 nvarchar(max) = N'{
   "Fields":[
      {"FieldValue":[{"key":"value"}]}
   ]
}'
SELECT *
FROM OPENJSON(@json2, '$.Fields') WITH (
  FieldValue NVARCHAR(MAX) '$.FieldValue' AS JSON
) j1
CROSS APPLY OPENJSON(j1.FieldValue) WITH (
  [key] varchar(50) '$.key'
) j2
```

| FieldValue | key |
| --- | --- |
| [{"key":"value"}] | value |

Comment: `nvarchar(max)` might be wiser than `varchar(max)` for the embedded JSON

Comment: Thanks Zhorov, this worked perfectly for me!